# Autocompletion of column names or list element names R in VSCode

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I really like to use VSCode but one limitation compared to rstudio for R is that vscode is unable to tab autocomplete column names for dataframes or named elements in lists. See screen shots below. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Rstudio autocomplete

[image: Rstudio autocomplete:]

NO autocomplete in VSCode

[image: NO autocomplete in VSCode]

(FYI similar question asked 4yrs ago no answers)

None of the r extensions or intellisense that I know of helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to install the package `languageserver`. Here is the link https://github.com/REditorSupport/languageserver

You should follow the instruction to configuration the extensions
[image]

---

From VSC extension market, maybe you need `R` extension as well

[image]

and please carefully read the details and check if you need something specifically configured for your purpose

[image]